# GDAL output 3-band RGB in Python

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff

I am using the following code to output a floating point GeoTIFF file:

```
    driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
    outRaster = driver.Create(newRasterfn, cols, rows, 1, gdal.GDT_Float32)
    outRaster.SetGeoTransform((originX, pixelWidth, 0, originY, 0, pixelHeight))
    outband = outRaster.GetRasterBand(1)
    outband.WriteArray(array)
    outRasterSRS = osr.SpatialReference()
    outRasterSRS.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
    outRaster.SetProjection(outRasterSRS.ExportToWkt())
    outband.FlushCache()
```

When I import this into QGIS, I can view the image as a greyscale:

[image: img1]

And then alter the colors to a 'jet' colormap for a singleband pseudocolor:

[image: img2]

However, I would like to import the 2nd image with its colorscale / attributes to appear exactly as it is into Google Earth. When I import either, I get a black and white image:

[image: img3]

Therefore, I edited my code to be:

```
outRaster = driver.Create(newRasterfn, cols, rows, 3, gdal.GDT_Byte,options=['PHOTOMETRIC=RGB', 'PROFILE=GeoTIFF'])
#outRaster = driver.Create(newRasterfn, cols, rows, 1, gdal.GDT_Float32)
```

When I do this, I only get the red portion of the image:

[image: img4]

and loaded into QGIS:

[image: img5]

Not sure what I am overlooking here.